QM: General Solution of TDSE
Im currently reading Quantum Mechanics 2nd Edition by Bransden & Joachain and I am confused about a certain equation. Can somebody please help me out?
The equation in question is $(3.145)$ on page 119 of paragraph 3.7: Properties of the energy eigenfunctions. It is said that the generic solution of the TDSE (they explicitly refer to the most general form) $\Psi(r,t)$ can be written as $$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_EC_E(t)\psi_E(r)\tag{3.145},$$ with $\psi_E(r)$ the energy eigenfunctions. What confuses me is that this seems to hold for $V=V(r,t)$ (i.e. $H$ is time-dependent).
But, how can the energy eigenfunctions at all be derived, if $V$ is time-dependent? That doesn't make sense compared to the paragraphs before, where $V=V(t)$ was explicitly assumed for separation of variables to achieve those energy eigenfunctions.
That they really mean $V=V(r,t)$ in $(3.145)$ is seemingly emphasized by a derivation in section 3.8 that uses this equation. It is explicitly stated that they then use $V=V(r)$. So this must not be directly assumed in $(3.145)$, I think.

The exact wording about $(3.145)$:
We shall postulate that the energy spectrum obtained by solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation $(3.102)$ represents all the physically realizable energies of the system. This implies that the set of energy eigenfunctions is complete, in the sense that any physically admissible wave function can be expressed as a superposition of them. The general solution $\Psi(r,t)$ of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation $(3.21)$ can therefore be expanded in terms of the energy eigenfunctions as
$$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_EC_E(t)\psi_E(r)\tag{3.145},$$
where the expansion coefficients $C_E(t)$ depend on the time. In writing the above equation, we have dropped the degeneracy index for notational simplicity, it being understood that the summation includes αα times an energy eigenvalue whose degeneracy is of order $\alpha$.
And the part I'm talking about in my last paragraph: 
In the preceding section we have seen that the general solution $\Psi(r,t)$ of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation $(3.21)$ can be expanded in terms of the energy eigenfunctions $\psi_E(r)$ according to $(3.145)$. We shall now determine the expansion coefficients $C_E(t)$ for the case of a particle moving in a time-independent potential $V(r)$. To this end, we substitute $(3.145)$ in the Schrödinger wave equation $(3.21)$, and use the facts that the Hamiltonian $H$ is time-independent and that $H\psi_E=E\psi$​.

Can you quote the exact wording for $V=V(r,t)$? You're right in saying that separation of variables assumes a time-independent hamiltonian.

@agaminon Hi! I've edited it into the question - hopefully it helps.


But, how can the energy eigenfunctions at all be derived, if $V$ is time-dependent? That doesn't make sense compared to the paragraphs before, where $V=V(t)$ was explicitly assumed for separation of variables to achieve those energy eigenfunctions.

Separation of variables does not matter for defining eigenfunctions. The decisive part of definition of Hamiltonian eigenfunctions $\Phi(\mathbf r)$ is that they obey the equation
$$
\hat{H} \Phi (\mathbf r) = \epsilon \Phi(\mathbf r).
$$
There may be many different eigenfunctions obeying the above equation with the same $\epsilon$ (this math phenomenon is called degeneracy).
The Hamiltonian may depend on some parameter $\lambda$ that can be varied, and then also eigenvalues and eigenfunctions may depend on $\lambda$. We can indicate this by writing the eigenvalue equation with explicit show of $\lambda$:
$$
\hat{H}_{\lambda} \Phi_{\lambda}(\mathbf r) = \epsilon_\lambda\Phi_{\lambda}(\mathbf r).
$$
(Often, continuous change of $\lambda$ from zero to non-zero can cause a set of eigenfunctions for the same eigenvalue $\epsilon$ to change so that each eigenfunction $\Phi_{lm...}$ is associated with different eigenvalue $\epsilon_{lm...}$. This is called removal of degeneracy.)
For example, an atom in external electric field can be described by an Hamiltonian with interaction term
$$
H_{int} = -qzE_z.
$$
Here, $z$ is coordinate of the electron, and $\lambda = E_z$ is the parameter.
The parameter $\lambda$ may depend on time, and then eigenvalues and eigenfunctions may depend on time. E.g. the electric field may be a harmonic function of time, $E_z = E_0\sin \omega t$; and eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the total time-dependent Hamiltonian will then depend on time. Alternatively, the time $t$ itself can be regarded as such parameter, continuously linearly increasing in time.
We can make this explicit in writing the eigenvalue equation this way:
$$
\hat{H}_t \Phi_t(\mathbf r) = \epsilon_t \Phi_t(\mathbf r).
$$
With a time-dependent Hamiltonian, it is no longer possible to express $\psi(\mathbf r,t)$ obeying the time-dependent Schroedinger equation as a product of time-independent eigenfunction $\Phi(\mathbf r)$ and time-dependent factor $e^{-\frac{i\epsilon t}{\hbar}}$. But, if we assume the set of eigenfunctions $\Phi_{i,t}(\mathbf r)$ is a complete basis, we can still express any such $\psi$ function as infinite sum, a linear combination of functions $\Phi_{i,t}$:
$$
\psi(\mathbf r,t) = \sum_{i} c_{i}(t) \Phi_{i,t} (\mathbf r),
$$
where in each term, both factors, $c_i(t)$ and $\Phi_{i,t}$, depend on time.

I'm a bit confused because you're using the TDSE, while I think it's only valid in the case where $H$ is time independent (since we need $E$ to be constant for separating the TISE). Does this form an issue?

@Max Why do you think TDSE is valid only when $H$ is time-independent? TDSE is a postulate, assumed valid in different situations with different Hamiltonians, and including Hamiltonians dependent on time.

Oh I mixed them up, sorry. I meant to say that I believe the time-independent SE is only valid if $H$ is time-independent.

@Max The time-independent Schroedinger equation is the eigenvalue equation $\hat{H}\Phi = E\Phi$. It does not make sense to say it is valid or invalid, this is just a mathematical equation which defines eigenfunctions and eigenvalues associated with the Hamiltonian. A psi function obeying the time-dependent Schroedinger equation does not obey this eigenvalue equation. But this does not mean the eigenvalue equation is invalid.

@Max Maybe you're thinking TISE defines real psi functions occurring out there, but that is a misconception. It just defines eigenfunctions which can be used as a basis, the "real" psi function has to obey TDSE.

Alright, this makes sense! It makes me wonder, the authors don't write an explicit time-dependence in the eigenfunctions in the expansion $(3.145)$. What they write is $\psi_E(r)$. From your answer I see that these actually can be time-dependent. Do you know if it is common notation to state a time-dependent eigenfunction simply as $\psi_E(r)$?

@Max No, talking about time-dependent eigenfunctions is not common in introductory textbooks, but when it is done in more advanced texts, the fact eigenfunctions depend on the parameter (which may be time) is obvious.

Given that they don't explicitly state that the solution is for $V=V(r,t)$, and given that the solution they propose is separable, I believe that they mean the general solution for a time independent Hamiltonian. When the hamiltonian is time independent, the solution can be written as
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \exp\left(\frac{-i(t-t_0)}{\hbar}\hat{H}\right)|\psi(t_0)\rangle.$$
The Hamiltonian here is an operator. An operator can be written in terms of its spectral decomposition (assuming a non-degenerate spectrum, for simplicity)
$$\hat{H}=\sum_n E_n |n\rangle\langle n| = \sum_n E_n P_n. $$
The $E_n$ here are the eigenvalues and the $|n\rangle$ the eigenstates, the solution to the TISE. $P_n = |n\rangle\langle n|$ is the projector for the $n$-th eigenstate. It projects an arbitrary state $|\psi\rangle$ into a state proportional to $|n\rangle$ (or $0$, if the arbitrary state is orthogonal to the latter). This is just writing the operator in its eigenbasis, we are diagonalizing it. Then a function of this operator is
$$f(\hat{H}) = \sum_n f(E_n) P_n. $$
So the state will be
$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_n \exp\left(\frac{-i(t-t_0)}{\hbar}E_n\right)|n\rangle\langle n|\psi(t_0)\rangle = \sum_n c_n(t) |n\rangle ,$$
where I define
$$c_n(t) = \exp\left(\frac{-i(t-t_0)}{\hbar}E_n\right)\langle n|\psi(t_0)\rangle. $$
In terms of wavefunctions
$$\langle x |\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_n c_n(t) \psi_n(x), $$
which is exactly what the authors wrote, specifying that the coefficients have an exponential time dependence. I don't think you can assume a separable solution exists, even with arbitrary coefficients, for a general Hamiltonian. If you go further in the book, it's likely you'll encounter this result (maybe using a different notation).

Hmm... It would indeed sense if they meant a time-independent Hamiltonian. I still find it very strange that they say are so explicit it's the general solution to a TDSE, which doesn't assume $V=V(x)$. That just can't seem like an accident to me. But alright. Could you please explain what you meant with this solution being "separable"? And did you mean to write  $\langle{x}|\psi(t)\rangle$ in your last equation? Shouldn't that just be $\psi(t)$?

Separable means that you can write it as a product of two functions, each of them defined with different variables, $f(\vec{r})\phi(t)$. Now that I think about it though, the superposition itself is not necessarily separable, so the given solution could be a general solution!
And yes, I meant to write that. That's the way you write $\psi(x,t)$ in Dirac notation.

But we also concluded that in general we can't derive the "energy eigenfunctions " (i.e. the $\psi_n(r)$'s) in the case of a time-dependent Hamiltonian. The expansion won't really make much sense in that case then, right?

In typical (non-relativistic) quantum systems, there is a time-independent "background" Hamiltonian $H_0$ that describes the system in equilibrium conditions, and an array of time dependent perturbations that disturb the system from its background state.  These external disturbances are typically applied only over a relatively short window of time, so that the system in question is almost always described by the background Hamiltonian.  For example, atoms and molecules are typically described by an approximately time-independent Hamiltonian given by the positions of the ions and whatever static external fields are applied (although these are typically weak enough that they modify the spectra and eigenstates only slightly), and occasionally subjected to pulses of radiation that cause level transitions.
Under these conditions, it makes sense to describe the wave function in terms of the eigenstates/orbitals of the (approximately time-independent) background Hamiltonian, $H_0$.  If $H_0$ has a complete set of eigenstates $|\psi_E\rangle$ such that $H_0|\psi_E\rangle = E|\psi_E\rangle$, then an arbitrary time dependent wave function $|\psi(t)\rangle$ can be expanded as
\begin{align*}
|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_E \alpha_E(t)|\psi_E\rangle
\end{align*}
where $\alpha_E(t) = \langle \psi_E|\psi(t)\rangle$.  The time-dependent Schroedinger equation then induces an equivalent equation for the allowed coefficients $\alpha_E(t)$.
There are situations where it can be practical to use a time-dependent basis (i.e. basis functions $|\psi_E(t)\rangle$ that explicitly depend on time.)  In a somewhat elementary sense this is done in choosing "the interaction picture" for time-dependent perturbation theory (i.e. expanding $|\psi(t)\rangle$ in $e^{-iEt/\hbar}|\psi_E\rangle$ instead of $|\psi_E\rangle$, to absorb "most" of the time-dependence a priori), but it can also be useful more generally (e.g. in cases where a "fast" time-dependent perturbation is applied simultaneously with a slower Born-Oppenheimer process.)

Bransden & Joachain is a great book. You have uncovered a part that is somewhat cryptic.
If you trace the argument from Equation (3.19) to (3.21) and then scrutinise the crucial transition from Equation (3.94) to (3.98), you will realise that time-independent Hamiltonian is a necessary condition.
However, what B&J is likely trying to get at, at that ending of Section 3.7, is to preempt time dependent perturbation theory,  Section 9.1. The general idea there, is that $H=H_0+H_1$ where $H_0=-\frac{\nabla^2}{2m}+V(\vec r)$ and $H_1=H_1(t)$ is zero for all $t\leqslant0$ and is a small non-zero perturbation for $t>0$. The handling of such a perturbation is to expand the TDSE solution over the $H_0$ eigen-expansion.
That is a somewhat unfortunate presentation by B&J. You may safely ignore it until you reach Chapter 9.

Thanks for replying and referencing to the book. I am actually studying Chapter 9, but got quite confused when I looked back. By time-independent Hamiltonian is a necessary condition, do you mean that for equation (3.145)? I thought I could conclude from Ján Lalinský's answer that it is not necessary.

The argument for separation of variables required that f(t) and $\psi(\vec r)$ satisfy Equation (3.96)'s argument, so that Equation (3.97) and Equation (3.98) holds true. So, for beginners, this should be taken as gospel. However, when push comes to shove, we have to find some way to get answers, and one horrible way to do it, is to take each $V(\vec r,t)$ as $V_t(\vec r)$ that is fixed at each time slice, and approximately advance the wavefunction that way. Desperate measures for desperate people.

I understand that we can make (potentially strange) assumptions to hopefully simplify some things. I just wonder whether in the most general case if eqn. (3.145) is possible, not whether it actually leads to anything more. Would you agree with @Ján Lalinský' s answer?

I know what Jan is trying to say, and the general gist is correct. However, Equation (3.145) cannot be correct because it assumes that $\psi_E(\vec r)$ is a valid concept; it is not a valid concept when $H$ depends upon time, and instead it has to be $\psi_{E(t)}(\vec r,t)$ or some other complicated headache. That is, what Jan said could be made to work, but with a lot of subtleties-handling, but it has very little to do with what B&J is trying to say. It is just quite unfortunate that it is leading to a lot of confusion.

I totally agree with your last comment... I think the best way to go is to assume Jan's answer to be correct for understanding what is literally in the book, and then assuming applications (e.g. $V=V(x)$, perturbation assumptions) are nice, specific cases.

On the contrary, I think it is only going to be way more confusing to consider time-dependent Hamiltonians as having a complete set of eigenfunctions, because the time evolution is exceedingly nontrivial. It will instead make conversation extremely awkward. The more sensible way forward is to always specify that you are considering what Jan is saying, in the extremely rare cases of its use. This way, the person you are conversing with, will be least likely to be confused.

@Max in case the variation of the Hamiltonian is fast(in some technical sense, e.g. compared to oscillation due to $e^{-i(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1)t/\hbar})$, and goes to zero for long times, then it is common to expand $\psi$ in eigenfunctions of the time-independent part $H_0$. In case variation of the Hamiltonian is slow  enough(adiabatic), then it is useful to expand $\psi$ in eigenfunctions of time-dependent $H(t)$. Both methods can be used in all cases, but one is physically more convenient than the other in one or the other case.


It is said that the generic solution of the TDSE (they explicitly refer to the most general form) $\Psi(r,t)$ can be written as $$\Psi(r,t)=\sum_EC_E(t)\psi_E(r)\tag{3.145},$$ with $\psi_E(r)$ the energy eigenfunctions.

Your statement "with $\psi_E(r)$ the energy eigenfunctions" means that the $\psi_E(r)$ satisfy:
$$
\hat H_1 \psi_E(r) = E\psi_E(r)\;, \tag{1}
$$
for some time-independent $H_1$. The hamiltonian $H_1$ has to be time independent because the $\psi_E$ are time-independnent and thus can not solve Eq. (1) if $H_1$ changes in time.

What confuses me is that this seems to hold for $V=V(r,t)$ (i.e. $H$ is time-dependent).

The sum written in your Eq. (3.145) can satisfy the TDSE with a time dependent potential.
For example, write:
$$
\hat H(r,t) = \hat H_1(r) + \hat V(r,t)
$$
and then you can have your time-independent basis $\psi_E(r)$ satisfy
$$
\hat H_1(r)\psi_E(r) = E \psi_E(r)
$$
and you can still have:
$$
i\frac{\partial \Psi(r,t)}{\partial t} = \hat H(r,t)\Psi(r,t)\;
$$
as long as you have
$$
i\frac{dC_E}{dt} = \sum_{E'}\left(E\delta_{E,E'}+\langle E|\hat V(r,t)|E'\rangle\right)C_{E'}
$$
